# Is EdgeVanna a good place to get a server for a validator

Tags: validator

Super interested in running a validator. Not sure where to start. Any help pointing me in the right direction would be great! My main concern is if I pay monthly to a hosting service like edgevanna will it be at least a little worth it or profitable in the least to cover the hosting fees?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, Edgevana among others is a great place to run your validator. Latitude and Cherry Servers are also good. If you're just starting and want to turn profitable, you need to factor in voting costs as well as your server costs. Voting costs are around 2 sol per epoch, which averages to 1 sol a day.

You can use the [validator profit calculator](https://cogentcrypto.io/ValidatorProfitCalculator) by Cogent Crypto to calculate your expenses, and how much stake you'll need to be breakeven or profitable.